# How to wrap a text after slash?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html

[image: Example]
Hi everybody! I want to wrap my text in column after slash "/".
I tried to use `word-wrap: normal;` but it split it by my column width.
So how can I shift the word "Wife" to the next line?

Comment: Could you please add a demo ?.

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker I'm using kendo grid the text changes dynamically.

Comment: @user3818229 can you share your compiled html code

Comment: Maybe you want something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/195/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `word-break: break-all;` and `word-wrap: break-word;` get "Husband/Wife" as a single word, the only alternative (without javascript) that I have in mind is the `<wbr>` (word break opportunity) tag. Example:

```
Husband/<wbr>Wife
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qd2mqebm/)

`<wbr>` applied with Javascript:

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
s = s.replace("/","/<wbr>"); 
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = s;
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/631wpxy4/)

`<wbr>` applied multiple times in multiple elements with Javascript:

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/obkxy5mj/)

Comment: Yeah, I know but my text building by some property value. So It would be hard to parse string and replace it.

Comment: Theree is now way to do something like you did using `style`, right? Kendo fill the text dynamically, I can't see it even in compiled html.